# Make the "Log in using …" texts hyperlinks to support keyboard navigation

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, login, keyboard-shortcuts

In Google Chrome, and a number of other browsers that I've used, I can search for text in a page, and if one of the matches ends up being a hyperlink, I can end the search once it's selected, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to follow the link.

For instance, if I visit [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/), hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, type `strend`, the STRENDS entry in the table of contents is highlighted.  If I then hit <kbd>Escape</kbd>, the link is focused, and I can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to follow it.

This doesn't work on the login pages though, because the "Log in using …" texts aren't hyperlinks.

Similarly, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through the links on a page missing the "Log in using …" elements.

Would it be very difficult to make these actual hyperlinks so that we can select them without need to click on them with a mouse?  If not, I'd request that they be made hyperlinks.

[image: freehand red showing the problem]